# How to build all the branches at the same time with jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Multibranch Pipeline project connected with a github repository.
The thing is that some time ago when we clicked "scan repository now" it built all the branches that had differences with the branch master/master35
But lately when we click "scan repository now" it just build 4-5 of 30 branches and ignore the others.

I have checked and there are differences between those branches that jenkins ignores and the master/master35 branch.
If I click "build now" on those branches that git ignores it builds correctly.

This is the Jenkinsfile on every branch:

```
node {
    stage('checkout') {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master35') {
            def jobs = []
            Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {
                jobs.push(it.name)
            };

            jobs.each{
                if (!it.endsWith('master35')){
                    try{
                        build 'DGF-MOODLE/'+it
                    }catch(Exception ex) {
                        println(ex)
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    stage('deploy') {
        echo 'branch name ' + env.BRANCH_NAME
        if (!env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("master") && !env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("develop") && !env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("master35") && !env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("develop35") && !env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("PR")) {
            git url: "https://"+dgf_moodle_token+"@github.com/----/-----.git",
            branch: env.BRANCH_NAME
            sh 'git config --global user.name "-----"'
            sh 'git config --global user.mail "-----"'
            sh 'git merge origin/master35'
            sh 'git push origin '+ env.BRANCH_NAME
        }
    }
    stage('clean') {
        cleanWs()
    }
}
```

I'm not a jenkins expert so I'm not even sure if "scan repository now" should build the branch too.

Could you guys tell me what can I do to build the branch when I click "scan repository now" or any other way to build all the branches on the same job?

thank you!

Comment: To my knowledge "Scan repository now" will just check to see if there are any changes in each respective branch that Jenkins is unaware of. It doesn't compare to master, but it will build a branch if there are committed changes in that branch that has not yet been built.